# Eclipse not copying JARs from User Libraries into lib folder when deploying on weblogic

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

We are transitioning from MyEclipse to regular free Eclipse.  Before, when deploying to a weblogic server, MyEclipse would automatically copy any JARs referenced as libraries as required.

However, now when we do the same using regular free Eclipse, we get ClassNotFoundExceptions upon deployment for classes contained in the JARs referenced in the User Libraries.  If we add the JAR file directly into the WEB-INF/lib folder, it works as expected but we don't want to do this.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

I've been researching on here and on the internet in general for the last three hours but with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your Dynamic Web Project's Deployment Assembly property page to control what gets deployed to where. http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.2.0/NewAndNoteworthy/javaee.php

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks!  It's a shame it doesn't do this automatically though.  In MyEclipse, any libraries added to a project's build path are automatically deployed to the web server.  This is a good solution to the problem though.